# uint64_t is only 32 bits wide?

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
    uint64_t k = 1 << 32;
    return 0;
}
```

I try to do this operation (since I expect `k` to be 64 bit wide, yet I get a warning about exceeding the width. Am I wrong to thing `uint64_t` will always be 64 bit?

Comment: try making the *1* 64 bits wide

Answer (score 4):

What you do with the result of an operation has no effect on how that operation is performed. The type rules in C++ are complicated enough already -- if you had to take into account what you did with the result to figure out how the operation would be performed, they would be much more complex.

You did `1 << 32`. Why would you expect that to produce a 64 bit result?

Try

```
uint64_t k = 1;
k <<= 32;
```

Comment: or `uint64_t k = 1ull << 32;`

Comment: Right, there are any number of ways you can do it.